# snap not loading within a VM of ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vmware, snap

Running Ubuntu 20.04 in VM, snap (hamster-snap) not loading, seems to be running in background but no gui. How do I get snap working within a VM install? Ran

```
snap connect hamster-snap:system-observe
```

As advised following snap install, do I need to give snap access to the display somehow? Accessing VM using RDP (VM running xRDP)
tried rebooting several times and uninstalling, rebooting then re-install but still nothing, that snap doesn't give any errors. tried another snap (plumber)
"No protocol specified qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :10.0 qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb."

Comment: Yes tried rebooting several times and uninstalling rebooting then re-install but still nothing, that snap doesn't give any errors. tried another snap (plumber)

Comment: No protocol specified
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :10.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Comment: That's important. It should be part of your Question above instead of buried in a (rarely read) comment.